# GitHub API Revoke Access Token

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth, access-token, github-api

i have successfully integrated github in my ios App by using GitHub API3 .

but my problem is i am not able to delete/revoke access token.

i tried following code

```
NSString * querystr= @"https://api.github.com/authorizations";    

// i tried this url url also https://api.github.com/authorizations?client_id=1234yyrhrh

NSMutableURLRequest *request2 = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:querystr]];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request2 queue:theQ
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) 
{
      NSArray * array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
      NSLog(@"%@",array);
}];
```

i am not getting any error, but array is printing following message

```
"documentation_url" = "http://developer.github.com/v3";
 message = "Not Found";
```

thanks in advance

Comment: To revoke your own tokens, you need to authenticate using Basic Auth: http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#oauth-authorizations-api. To delete OAuth tokens of other users, you need to use a different endpoint: http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#revoke-an-authorization-for-an-application.

Comment: @IvanZuzak do you have any idea how it can be done . . . i trying but not able to get it using basic authentication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

finally i solved it . . . :)

```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.github.com/applications/%@/tokens/%@",GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,token]];

   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   NSString *theUsername = GITHUB_CLIENT_ID;
   NSString *thePassword = GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET;

   [request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@",[self base64forData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@",theUsername,thePassword] dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
   [request setHTTPMethod:@"DELETE"];
   [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

   NSError *error = nil;
   NSURLResponse *response;

   [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];



- (NSString*)base64forData:(NSData*)theData
{
    const uint8_t* input = (const uint8_t*)[theData bytes];
    NSInteger length = [theData length];

    static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];
    uint8_t* output = (uint8_t*)data.mutableBytes;

    NSInteger i;
    for (i=0; i < length; i += 3) {
        NSInteger value = 0;
        NSInteger j;
        for (j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
            value <<= 8;

            if (j < length) {
                value |= (0xFF & input[j]);
            }
        }

        NSInteger theIndex = (i / 3) * 4;
        output[theIndex + 0] =                    table[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 1] =                    table[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? table[(value >> 6)  & 0x3F] : '=';
        output[theIndex + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? table[(value >> 0)  & 0x3F] : '=';
    }

    return [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
}
```